# Которых или которые?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, союзные-слова

Это подруги, **которых** я заслуживаю.
Это подруги, **которые** я заслуживаю.

Как правильно?

Comment: Ну конечно, "которых" - это ведь не "подушки", а живые существа. Вот если бы "которые меня заслуживают"...

Comment: _Alex_ander_, мне кажется, что дело здесь не в живых существах, а в разном управлении глаголов "заслуживать" и "заслужить" (тут вообще нет **кого**, только **чего** и **что**). Для сравнения можно посмотреть прошедшее время: _Это подушки, **которых** я заслуживал_; _Это подушки, **которые** я заслужил_.

Comment: Управление  "подушками" зависит от контекста, поскольку значение слова "заслуживаю" может быть разным, в частности буквальным (напр. переходя на новый уровень компьютерной игры, я всякий раз заслуживаю подушки разного цвета и достоинства). Управление "чего" возникает только тогда, когда слово "заслуживаю" означает "достоин". _Безвариантное_ же управление "чего"  возникает в случае возвратного глагола "удостаиваюсь".

Comment: "Я зарабатываю гроши. Я заслуживаю гроши." Действительно в другом смысле другое управление. Но было неожиданно узнать, что в словарях все строго.

Comment: Нет же! Я заслуживаю грошей — я заслужил гроши. Посмотрите в Нацкорпусе "я заслуживаю". (https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&req=%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E&g=i_doc&format=html&spp=50&text=lexform&dpp=10&kwsz=5&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) Я всякий раз заслуживаю (достоин) **подушек** разного цвета и достоинства.

Comment: Вы правы, это почти всегда ошибка, кроме экзотических случаев. Я заслуживаю (в смысле удостаиваюсь) грошей. Я заслуживаю (в смысле зарабатываю) гроши.

Answer (score 2):

Управление в русском языке:
[*заслуживать*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)  **чего** (не что!). *Сообщение заслуживает доверия; Проект заслуживает одобрения.*

Правильно так: *Это подруги, **которых** я заслуживаю.*

В придаточном предложении союзное слово "которых" (чего? — Р. п., мн. ч.) подменяет существительное "подруги", а ставится оно [слово] в родительном падеже (как того требует управляющий глагол "заслуживать").

*Ты дашь мне всех женщин, **которых** я заслуживаю* (из фильма "Хозяева ночи").
*Герои, **которых** мы заслуживаем* (название статьи).

P. S. Думаю, что проблема здесь в том, что происходит путаница с управлением в глаголах: **заслуживать** (чего) и [**заслужить**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (что (не чего!)).