# Склонение в «заслуживать к себе особого отношения (внимания)»

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление, родительный-или-винительный

> Мы – избранные существа, заслуживающие к себе особое отношение.

Должны ли два последних слова быть в именительном падеже или допускается написание в родительном падеже?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Заслужить что или заслужить чего, заслуживать что или заслуживать чего?**
>
> Управление зависит от вида глагола. Правильно: *заслужить что* (не чего!), напр.: *спортсмен заслужил награду; Россия заслужила эти Игры.* Но: *заслуживать чего* (не что!), напр.: *проект заслуживает одобрения; этот человек заслуживает уважения* ([Грамота ру](http://gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_2869)).

Правильно так:

*Мы – избранные существа, **заслуживающие** к себе особо**го** отношени**я*** (*заслуживающий* – причастие настоящего времени от *[заслуживать](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C);* родительный падеж).

*Мы – избранные существа, **заслужившие** к себе особо**е** отношен**ие*** (*заслуживший* – причастие прошедшего времени от *[заслужить](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C);* падеж в этом случае не именительный, а винительный).

Comment: Саша, я бы дополнила твою *правильность*: Мы — избранные существа, заслуживающие к себе особого отношения (заслуживающий — причастие настоящего времени от заслуживать; родительный падеж). Мы — избранные существа, заслужившие к себе особое отношение (заслуживший — причастие прошедшего времени от заслужить; падеж в этом случае не именительный, а винительный). P. S. О правке: если мы оформляем предложение вертикальной линией (то есть собственно цитатой), то, считаю, кавычки уже не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма. Не хотел перегружать, думал и так всё понятно. Но согласен, изменил.

Comment: Александр, спасибо за своевременный ответ!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Когда-то я отвечала на подобный вопрос (даже поспорить пыталась). [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466883/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5]

Comment: Ага, посмотрел, вспомнил. Там всё отлично! Мой голос уже там полтора года.